Why does this tkinter image animation not delay properly?
Here's my attempt, modified from another post, to create a minimal loop where I create a numpy array and display it. (For convenience I have a Start button.)
It works fine, with one exception -- it runs at full speed, regardless of what delay I put in as the first argument to self.after (it's 1000 in the example below. Changing this arg has no visible effect.)
What am I missing? (I am running python 3.8.3. Oh, that's apparently a very old version. Damn. I'll go update just in case that's related to the issue.)
from PIL import ImageTk
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width = 1200, height=1200)
        self.canvas.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_animation).pack()

    def start_animation(self):
        self.canvas.delete('all')

        # generate a random test frame
        im = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1024,1024,3), dtype="uint8")
        im1 = Image.fromarray(im, 'RGB')
        im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im1)

        self.canvas.create_image(600, 600, image=im2)
        self.update()
        self.after(1000, self.start_animation())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()


convert self.after(1000, self.start_animation()) to self.after(1000, self.start_animation) count the number of brackets, also convert im2 to self.im2

I apparently trashed my pycharm installation by installing 3.12, so it'll be a while before I can run your fix (distutils issue.). Ooh I see what I did wrong -- I invoked the function recursively rather than passing a function pointer. Ugh. Thanks. Why the self.im2 though? (Or why not self.im1 also?)

when im2 is out of scope the image will be cleared, that's how tkinter works, you just prevent it from going out of scope

why do I care since it's presumably already been copied to the canvas (in this particular case)? I see your point in keeping the numpy array around rather than creating it every time, though. I wasn't aware I had to explicitly assign stuff to self to keep it alive after function exit (out of practice here I am.)

why do I care since it's presumably already been copied to the canvas no, it is not, that's only how tkinter works

The canvas is cleared if I don't have self.im2? Even though I explicitly invoke update()? I can't quite figure out the mental model of operation there. Note im2 only overwrites part of the canvas.

In tkinter, if there are no references to an image, it gets deleted from memory. This is to avoid memory leaks. Technically, there could have been code that keeps track of what is in the canvas and check if each image is still displayed but that's a lot of code the creators of tkinter didn't want to code.

Some points here

Value for option command for a tk.Button should be a function, not the result of that function.

tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_animation)


There should be a reference for your ImageTk.PhotoImage object, or it won't shown on your canvas.

self.im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im1)


Image not imported from Pillow.

Exaample Code
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width = 200, height=200)
        self.canvas.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_animation).pack()

    def start_animation(self):
        self.canvas.delete('all')

        # generate a random test frame
        im = np.random.randint(0, 255, (200, 200, 3), dtype="uint8")
        im1 = Image.fromarray(im, 'RGB')
        self.im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im1)

        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.im2, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.update()
        self.after(1000, self.start_animation)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()



Thank you for correcting my code in detail.
